# How to handle pushnotification service in iphone running app

Tags: iphone

I have implemented push notification service in iphone device, but running app will not get the notification service alert message, how to handle the APN service in running app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just implement in your application delegate

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

and you'll be happy =)

Answer (score 0):

Implement the following code in the delegate method:

```
(void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    NSString *reminderText = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
}
```

Also follow the link. It must help you.

http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/7/31/adding-local-notifications-with-ios-4.html